# Is it better to make onClickListeners with jQuery or as attributes on the html tag?

Tags: javascript

The question says it all. What are the pros and cons of adding on.click listeners from jQuery vs setting a function name as an attribute and then define the method in the included .js file?

Comment: Neither. It's best to use `element.addEventListener` but nobody does that anymore :D

Comment: What is used nowadays?

Comment: What do you mean with `setting a function name as an attribute and then define the method in the included .js file` you need to provide examples to explain better.

Comment: Setting the onclick attribute on the html tag, and then define what should happen in another file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping your HTML clean, and your JavaScript unobtrusive means...

Using HTML attributes to declare event handlers is considered 'none of the HTML's business':

```
<img src="thumbnail-1.jpg" onclick="showLarge()">
```

Referencing specific HTML elements in your JavaScript equally whiffs of a similar cross-contamination problem:

```
<img src="thumbnail-1.jpg" id="myPic">
...
$('#myPic').on('click', showLarge);
```

Better to attach events to your HTML element via something more, um... reusable:

```
<img src="thumbnail-1.jpg">
...
$('[src^="thumbnail-"]').on('click', showLarge);
```

...which would just not be possible when using HTML attributes to declare event handlers.

You can still set event handlers in jQuery via a named function.  The advantage of the jQuery technique is if your event handler is designed to be reusable, it will attach the event handler to all matching elements on the page.  You can run the JavaScript globally on every page of your website, instead of having JavaScript specifically for a particular page.

The other JavaScript techniques for declaring event handlers are:

- element.eventName = handler; e.g. `element.onclick = showLarge;`
- element.addEventListener(eventName, handler); e.g. `element.addEventListener('click', showLarge);`

These work fine, too.  The first technique only allows you to declare one handler for that event for that element, so from a reusability perspective, is not suitable for declaring a reusable generic handler because it would be possible for it to interfere with other handlers or vice versa.

The second technique used to go by another name in Internet Explorer (attachEvent), but addEventListener was introduced in IE9.  JQuery handled this browser compatibility problem.

Without jQuery, the author would need to locate the elements and add the event handler function to all matching events.  Therefore:

```
$('[src^="thumbnail-"]').on('click', showLarge);
```

would perhaps be:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[src^="thumbnail-"]').forEach(function(element){
  element.addEventListener('click', showLarge);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight.